# GCE - No stackdriver memory metrics for nodes

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes, stackdriver

I have set up my Kubernetes 1.3.4 cluster on GCE with

`export KUBE_ENABLE_CLUSTER_MONITORING=google`

This works quite nicely, I get application logs (for some reason in the *Container Engine* section, but well) and also pod and node metrics.

The only thing that is missing are the node memory metrics, only CPU is shown (see screenshot)

[No memory metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhmYH.png)

In the heapster logs I see tons of lines like this

```
{
 metadata: {
  severity: "ERROR"    
  projectId: "<project-id>"    
  serviceName: "container.googleapis.com"    
  zone: "europe-west1-d"    
  labels: {
   container.googleapis.com/cluster_name: "production"     
   compute.googleapis.com/resource_type: "instance"     
   compute.googleapis.com/resource_name: "fluentd-cloud-logging-production-minion-group-p0w8"     
   container.googleapis.com/instance_id: "6772154497331326454"     
   container.googleapis.com/pod_name: "heapster-v1.1.0-2102007506-23b3e"     
   compute.googleapis.com/resource_id: "6772154497331326454"     
   container.googleapis.com/stream: "stderr"     
   container.googleapis.com/namespace_name: "kube-system"     
   container.googleapis.com/container_name: "heapster"     
  }
  timestamp: "2016-09-13T14:40:08.000Z"    
  projectNumber: "930564692351"    
 }
 textPayload: "E0913 14:40:08.665035       1 gcm.go:179] Error while sending request to GCM googleapi: Error 400: Timeseries 76, point: start is not older than end, for a cumulative metric, invalidParameter
"   
 insertId: "pt5bo7g132r266"   
 log: "heapster"   
}
```

Not sure if this is related.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, we switched to GKE .. there it works

Comment: It didn't work for a long time on GKE either - it was issue between stackdriver and heapster, iirc, that got resolved later on - we used to complain about it often :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running your cluster using GCE instead of GKE 
You should install the [stackdriver agent](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent#linux-install) and verify the credentials that agent is using to communicate with stackdriver [link](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/troubleshooting#verify-project)

If you are using linux you can install the agent by executing:

```
curl -sSO https://dl.google.com/cloudagents/install-monitoring-agent.sh
sudo bash install-monitoring-agent.sh
```

and you can check your credentials running the following command:

```
sudo cat $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
sudo cat /etc/google/auth/application_default_credentials.json
```